# 0% code coverage when creating unit test Trigger from a Custom Object

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage, after-trigger

I have created a simple trigger from a custom object that will auto create new Case when saving Global Client Satisfaction information. However, i still getting 0% code coverage even though the unit test is passed.

I am newbie in creating a trigger in SF.

I would greatly appreciate if you could help me to solve this problem as this is also my firs time to deploy a trigger in production. Thanks

---

Trigger:

```
Trigger CreateNewCaseatHighRisk on Global_Client_Satisfaction__c (after Insert) {

    List<Case> newcase = new List<Case>();

    for (Global_Client_Satisfaction__c gcs: Trigger.New){

            if (gcs.CSAT_Rating__c == '-3'){

            Case newcaseforGCS = new Case();

            newcaseforGCS.Global_Customer_Satisfaction__c = gcs.Id;

            newcaseforGCS.AccountId = gcs.Account_Name__c;
            newcaseforGCS.ContactId = gcs.Contact_Name__c;
            newcaseforGCS.Status = 'Open';
            newcaseforGCS.Subject = gcs.CSAT_Subject__c;
            newcaseforGCS.Type = 'CSAT-High Risk Account';

            newcase.add(newcaseforGCS);

        }
    }

    insert newcase;


}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
Public class TestCreateNewCaseatHighRisk {

static testmethod void insertCase()    {

    Case c = new Case();
    c.Status = 'Open';
    c.AccountId = '0016300000PUPy9';
    c.Type = 'CSAT-High Risk Account';
    c.Subject = 'Test Subject';
    c.ContactId = '0036300000J462j';
    c.Global_Customer_Satisfaction__c = 'a1N63000000Zakd'; 

    insert c;
   }
}
```

Thank you! JP :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason you are not seeing any code coverage is, you wrote a trigger for object Global_Client_Satisfaction__c and in test class you are trying to creating a new case. Instead of creating a new case, create a new Global_Client_Satisfaction__c record.

While you are creating the record make sure that SAT_Rating__c  field value is 3 as that's the only condition your trigger is functioning on to create a case

Answer (score 0):

I think you should insert a Global_Client_Satisfaction__c instead of a case in your test method. Since you trigger is on Global_Client_Satisfaction__c. Please verify.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Account, Contact and then create Global_Client_Satisfaction__c record.

So, after insert, this trigger will fire and will create the case.

```
//create Account
Account acct = new Account (Name='test');
insert acct;

//create Contact
Contact con = new Contact (LastName = 'MyContact'; AccountId = acct.Id);
insert con;

//create Global_Client_Satisfaction__c record

Global_Client_Satisfaction__c gc = new Global_Client_Satisfaction__c();
gc.CSAT_Rating__c = '-3';
gc.AccountId = acct.id;
gc.ContactId = con.id;
gc.CSAT_Subject__c = 'My Subject';
insert gc;
```

Follow [Testing Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm)

By the way, for this kind of requirement, you could use Process Builder rather than trigger, so that you do not need to write any test classes.

Comment: thank you! @Santanu Boral.. I really appreciate your help.. Actually, i still don't know how to use Process Builder. But i will take note of that.. Thanks again..